# How to set permissions to create a vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Every time I try to run `vagrant init` I get this error message.

The user that is running Vagrant doesn't have the proper permissions
to write a Vagrantfile to the specified location. Please ensure that
you call `vagrant init` in a location where the proper permissions
are in place to create a Vagrantfile.

I'm trying to set up Vagrant for the first time. It's just a Windows 10 laptop, and I'm running the command from this directory; `C:\Users\admin\Documents\z\bin>`

I've looked at that directory and it seems to have full permissions allowed.

Comment: why dont you try to run it from C:\Users\{youruser}\vagrant? i think that should work. even if you are the admin user, vagrant may not work from the admin user's folder.

Comment: I just checked this - it sounded good to me - but the only users I've got are admin and public. Not sure I want to install it in the public folder, but there shouldn't be much risk, should there? Apologies it's taken so long to reply. Wasn't looking at this over the Easter weekend.